# Audio not working on new install of 11.10

Tags: 11.10

I am excited to join this community! I am having an audio issue when it comes to flash videos. I have checked the sound settings from the volume icon next to the time at the top navigation bar and all seems to be in order, though no audio is present when watching flash videos.

I am new to all this so that is why I am asking for help. There seemed to be a question similar to this, however the solution has not worked for me :-(

Any help on this would be Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I had a no audio issue that was because I installed from alternate and it didn't pull in all the alsa stuff.  I also had a 'some flash videos have no audio' problem that had to do with a hosed ffmpeg h264 decoder.

You could try un-installing and re-installing ubuntu-restricted.  For the uninstall you should also autoremove.  That should do it if there's not an overlooked dependency.